# Effect of string on pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string

[image]

Friction is absent everywhere threads and pulleys are massless.
In block C of figure 1 and 2 acceleration is non zero whereas in figure 3 it is 0.
My reasoning is that in the first figure there is no pulling force on pulley so there must be no acceleration.
Whereas in figure 3 a force f acts on the string which must pull the entire system along as it is connected to the pulley.
Please help.
 I'm having a confusion with determining where and when acceleration due to force on pulley comes into picture, not pertaining to these sums in particular.

Comment: Could you upload a better picture and give some explanation in words on what is depicted? Particularly the first figure is very hard to read. Are the big blocks with label "C" movable or fixed?  Acceleration comes into the picture through Newton's laws. If you have a force $F$ acting on a body of mass $m$ the acceleration is $a=F/m$. The force you have in fig 2 is gravitation acting on the free hanging mass. The force you have in fig 3 is external (=you pulling on the string).  You just need to be careful what masses you put in the equations for gravitational force and in the equation for $a$.

Comment: A better diagram would be good.

Comment: Mass C is free to move in each case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are correct. The force on each pulley is the sum of string tension from each direction. The horizontal components of this force must be balanced by another force in order for C to remain stationary.

Figure 1: As A falls the tension in the string will pull C & A together towards B.

Figure 2: The tension acting all horizontally on the left pulley is larger than the horizontal component of tension acting at 45$^\circ$ to horizontal on the right pulley, causing C to move horizontally. (It is assumed the vertical component and corresponding torque small enough to be negated by gravity.)

Figure 3: The tension on the two pulleys is equal and opposite they do not move. (There is a torque on C, which is assumed to be negated by gravity.)

Figure 1 in more detail:
A experiences the acceleration due to gravity, creating a tension $\vec T=\vec gM_a $. This force is transmitted along the string vertically into the pulley ($\vec T$), then horizontally out of the pulley ($\vec T_2$) to cause an acceleration of B. 
The pulley experiences an initial net translational force $\vec F=\vec T+\vec T_2$
The force F acts on C because the pulley is mounted on C.
The torque due to this force on C is neglected because the question is interested in horizontal accelerations of C not turning forces on C - although in reality in some configurations C could tip up.
The horizontal component of F is non-zero therefor C will move.

Comment: All pulleys are massless and frictionless, so where does torque come into picture??

Comment: And what is M in figure 1 it is not given

Comment: Torque that is rotating the entire body C would be due to the force applied through the pulley wheel mounting onto body C. This holds the pulley still when the string is tensioned (Nothing to do with the pulley turning.)

Comment: The A looks like an M in the blurred diagram, so it's a typo I meant to type A. (corrected)

Comment: Could you explain figure one in more detail please

Comment: And how are you so sure that horizontal components of tension in figure 3 cancel out?I mean in the second pulley some force on the pulley  is also "Wasted" in the form of vertical tension(since resultant force on each pulley must be same,and second pulley is given a vertical component so it's horizontal component mist be less

Comment: More details edited into answer.

Comment: As we are assuming the pulleys are lossless, the output tension is the same magnitude as the input tension. Only the direction is different.